# mysql index for max with where

Tags: mysql, indexing

trying to get the most recent computed_date where normalized_global_score is not NULL

```
SELECT max(`influencer_brand_scores`.computed_date) AS max_computed_date
FROM `influencer_brand_scores` 
WHERE (normalized_global_score IS NOT NULL)
```

This query is taking forever, and when I run explain on it I get:

> 1  SIMPLE  influencer_brand_scores ALL (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  3347895 Using where

So my question is, do I add an index on computed_date, or a compound index on normalized_global_score and computed_date, if so which should be first, or does it matter?

Comment: `NULL` is bad for index, any reason to store `NULL` value?

Comment: There is a nightly job to calculate the normalized_global_score number, so its possible the value can be null for a period of time, because of the complexity in calculating it, I dont see any easy way to remove it.

Comment: in this case i kind of think index on `computed_date` alone is much better, however, I might be wrong, keep me posted

Comment: @ajreal In theory you can be right. If NULL vales is relatively small part of the database then this index can be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first go with

```
INDEX( normalized_global_score, computed_date )
```

and if that didn't work well (because of normalized_global_score containing NULLs) make a new BOOLEAN column named `normalize_gobalcolumn_score_is_computed` and index that:

```
INDEX( normalize_gobalcolumn_score_is_computed, computed_date )
```

and have `normalized_global_score IS NOT NULL` replaced with `normalize_gobalcolumn_score_is_computed = TRUE` in your query.

Comment: Don't believe that with the boolean field this will be considerably faster.

Comment: BOOLEAN is synonym for TINYINT(1) and that type of column would be properly indexed and used. I remember MySql always having trouble with indexes containing NULL so I always avoided that, but I'm not sure if that has not been resolved in newer verisons of MySql.

Comment: From mathematical point of view, NULL values can't be the problem. The problem is data distribution. For instance if all the table have non-null values and just several records have null values then the this particular query can be slow. But TRUE/FALSE distribution is the same as NULL/NON-NULL distribution, so the query can still be slow.

Comment: It's not about mathematics here, it's about how MySql implements things, it doesn't behave the same when you have an `INT` column that may be null and you say `column IS NOT NULL` and when you have a `TINYINT(1) NOT NULL` column when you say `column = 1`.

Comment: NULL is nothing special in b-tree. The only advantage of boolean is the index deepness.

Comment: And BTW we have a two-part index here the distribution very much depends on `computed_date` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `influencer_brand_scores` 
    ADD INDEX `ibs_cindex` (`normalized_global_score`, `computed_date`);
```

Comment: @Joelio Updated! This should be fast enough. Everything depends on how many non-null values you have.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I dont think mysql supports ASC/DESC, not sure it matters much in this case.

Comment: @Joelio In theory the ordering may increase the probability of selecting the right starting point in single step. Sure it does not increase the performance considerably much in this case. In any case you are right, I have looked into the documentation and found that MySQL currently does not support index ordering :)